# BITFIELD_INVALID Discord.js V12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

BITFIELD_INVALID is my error and I cant find a fix related to my issue as soon as I run a command any command, just reply to me, also just a side note started happening when I deleted nuke.js

Please if this has happened to you tell me or just if you have the answer
Also i need to type mroe so this is unnecessary!!!,,,,

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1018:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1066:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1131:10) 
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:807:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:991:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.module.exports.run (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover2\stru
ctures\command.js:9:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover2\index.js:13
:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1102:14)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Loaded 13 commands!
Loadeded 3 events!
This is: Discover Now+#2319
C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover2\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitFi
eld.js:150
    throw new RangeError('BITFIELD_INVALID');
          ^

RangeError [BITFIELD_INVALID]: Invalid bitfield flag or number.
    at Function.resolve (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover2\node_modules\
discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:150:11)
    at Permissions.has (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover2\node_modules\d
iscord.js\src\util\BitField.js:45:28)
    at Permissions.has (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover2\node_modules\d
iscord.js\src\util\Permissions.js:45:85)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover2\events\message.
js:18:67)
    at Client.emit (node:events:376:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover2\nod
e_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Deskto
p\Discover2\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE
.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover2\
node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)        
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover2\node_m
odules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover2\node_
modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'BITFIELD_INVALID'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Loaded 13 commands!
Loadeded 3 events!
This is: Discover Now+#2319
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...

[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Loaded 13 commands!
Loadeded 3 events!
This is: Discover Now+#2319
C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover2\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitFi
eld.js:150
    throw new RangeError('BITFIELD_INVALID');
          ^

RangeError [BITFIELD_INVALID]: Invalid bitfield flag or number.
    at Function.resolve (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover2\node_modules\
discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:150:11)
    at Permissions.has (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover2\node_modules\d
iscord.js\src\util\BitField.js:45:28)
    at Permissions.has (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover2\node_modules\d
iscord.js\src\util\Permissions.js:45:85)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover2\events\message.
js:18:67)
    at Client.emit (node:events:376:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover2\nod
e_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Deskto
p\Discover2\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE
.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover2\
node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)        
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover2\node_m
odules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\james\OneDrive\Desktop\Discover2\node_
modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'BITFIELD_INVALID'
}
```

Here

const { owners } = require("../config");

```
module.exports = async (client, message) => {
    if (!message.guild || message.author.bot) return;
   
    const args = message.content.split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().slice(client.prefix.length).toLowerCase();
    const cmd = client.commands.get(command) || client.aliases.get(command);

    if (!message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(client.prefix)) return;

    if (!cmd) return;
    if (!message.guild.me.permissions.has(["SEND_MESSAGES"])) return;

    if (cmd.requirements.ownerOnly && !message.author.id.includes(owners)) return;

    if (cmd.requirements.userPerms && !message.member.permissions.has(cmd.requirements.userPerms && !message.author.id.includes(owners)))
        return message.reply(`you are missing the following permissions: ${missingPerms(message.member, cmd.requirements.userPerms)}`);
    if (cmd.requirements.clientPerms && !message.guild.me.permissions.has(cmd.requirements.clientPerms))
        return message.reply(`I am missing the following permissions: ${missingPerms(message.guild.me, cmd.requirements.clientPerms)}`)

    cmd.run(client, message, args);
}

const missingPerms = (member, perms) => {
    const missingPerms = member.permissions.missing(perms)
        .map(str => `\`${str.replace(/_/g, ' ').toUpperCase()}\``);

    return missingPerms.length > 1 ?
        `${missingPerms.slice(0, -1).join(", ")} and ${missingPerms.slice(-1)[0]}` :
        missingPerms[0];
}
```

Comment: Can you show the corresponding code

Comment: Index.js or what file?

Comment: The file from which the error originates from

Comment: Sure http://collabedit.com/n29e9

Comment: Please edit it into your existing post

Comment: Okay. Sure i'll do it now

Comment: Just did it the const got out of the code but yeah

Answer (score 0):

`Permission.has()` expects the first argument to be a `PermissionResolvable`, not an array. You should change the line where it says

```js
if (!message.guild.me.permissions.has(["SEND_MESSAGES"])) return;
```

to

```js
if (!message.guild.me.permissions.has("SEND_MESSAGES")) return;
```

Answer (score -1):

In the current version of discord 14.6.0 this happens when you are missing an intent. Assign an intent for the respective Function that you are trying to perform. For example like reading a message require `GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent` so you have to add it in intents array like this:

```
Client({intents:[GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent]});
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question though.